# Raise "onChange" event when Input Element changed by JavaScript from Popup Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, onchange

I have a webpage with a form element and a popup window (opened by window.open).

Both have jQuery available.

The popup window has a javascript that can change the form element in the opener window. That works perfectly by doing...

```
$(opener.document.formelement).val(vals[0]);
```

However by doing that the onChange event will not fire. That would be required by some other page elements, though. So I tried to fire the onChange event myself with

```
$(opener.document.formelement).change();
```

But that doesn't do anything.

Any hints? I definitely have to have that onChange event fired due to the architecture of other page elements.

This question is similar to [Call Javascript onchange event by programatically changing textbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735462/call-javascript-onchange-event-by-programatically-changing-textbox-value), but the suggested solutions from that question don't seem to work for me. Maybe that's because of the popup.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps its the cross-window that is hurting you...  Try making a function inside of opener that you call instead.  Might help?

In opener:

```
window.changeMyElement = function(value) {
  $(formelement).val(value).change();
}
```

From popup:

```
opener.changeMyElement(value);
```

Comment: opener.$('...').val(newval).change();

Answer (score 2):

This line is supposed to work:

```
$(opener.document.formelement).change();
```

According to the jQuery [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change) this line triggers the change event of each matched element.

If it's not working for you then there is a problem in your code somewhere. Can you trigger the onchange event by changing in the form element by hand?

Comment: Yes, I can. It works perfectly (although usually it should be a hidden element). However I suspect that it is forbidden to execute JavaScript in the "opener" from a popup due to security reasons. And firing an event would execute JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('controlname').fireEvent('onchange');
```

Or in your context:

```
$(opener.document.formelement).fireEvent('onchange');
```

Comment: Be warned that this is really only useful with IE, and only versions earlier than 9: http://help.dottoro.com/ljvtddtm.php